# Confusion of callback in JavaScript, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

```
statusDefault = status.textContent,

setStatus = function(s){
    status.textContent = s;//to set any status

    if(s != statusDefault){
        var delay = setTimeout(function(){
            setStatus(statusDefault);
            clearInterval(delay);
         },3000);
    }
};

setStatus('Testing..');
```

In the code above, I am not getting how it works. The default status changes to "Testing..", and after 3 seconds, it shows the default one again. I'm confused.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
statusDefault = status.textContent,
```

Copy the content before it is changed, caching it inside JavaScript.  This is the default content.

```
setStatus = function(s){
    status.textContent = s;
```

When the function is ran, set whatever the first argument is to `status`'s `textContent`.  Put more simply, it just changes whatever the element's content is when the function is ran.

```
if(s != statusDefault){
```

Check that the default value wasn't inputted first.

```
var delay = setTimeout(function(){
  setStatus(statusDefault);
  clearInterval(delay);
}, 3000);
```

Create a timeout that lasts 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds), after 3 seconds it calls itself internally again with `setStatus(statusDefault)`, this will reset the content to whatever it was originally (because of `statusDefault`), and it will also render the previous if statement false, so it doesn't create another timeout.

Here is a more brief (and probably easier to understand) list:

1. The original content is copied into `statusDefault`.
2. The content is set to `'Testing..'`.
3. `'Testing..'` is not equal to the original content.
4. Create a timeout that lasts 3 seconds (creating a 3 second delay).
5. Function calls itself internally again, passing in `statusDefault`.
6. The content is set to `statusDefault`.
7. If statement is false.  No more tasks, JavaScript is done.